# Executing tox in anaconda environment

Tags: python-3.x, tox, anaconda3

I am trying to `train mymodel` from `anaconda virtual environment`.I installed all the `packages` required. I tried to run the command `tox` from the folder where there are 3 files. requirements.txt which includes the `numpy,pandas libraries`with `versions`,`tox`, and  `regression model`. But I am getting the `error` ,`python.exe` not found in `venv`. But anaconda comes with python. How to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open anaconda prompt in virtual environment. Install tox-conda with
`pip install tox-conda`.
After installing go to the folder where you have all these files. Now execute the `tox` command or `tox -r` It will take sometime when you run for the first time.

Comment: It worked. I modified the ` requirements.txt` file and executed `tox -r` command